# Azure: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full

Tags: c#, mongodb, sockets, http, azure

We are migrating our website to azure and sometimes have an problem now with the following exception:

> An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full

We developed a search engine for long-distance-buses in germany and make thousands of requests to external services per day:

1. MongoDB
2. Azure Caches
3. Azure Storages (Blob)
4. External Apis

I guess, it are about 250.000 calls per day. More or less all of time are fast an very short. We have a timeout for all external apis with 8sec or less to prevent hanging requests.

The external apis are mostly accessed with the following class: http://pastebin.com/evNUVMXp

It worked fine so far, but everything was running on one machine only. At the moment I have 2 vms for `mongodb` and a website for 3 large instances running.

Any ideas what I can do to solve the problem?

Thank you for your help:
Sebastian

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

Main problem, I had, was with the with CosmosDB client instances. It is recommended that it is used as a static within application.

So, I would suggest to introduce data client to be used as a Singleton.

So usage of it in application would be then like:

```
DataClientFactory<EntityData>.Instance.DocumentDbRepository
```

Where `DataClientFactory`, implements Singleton patteren, and `DocumentDbRepository` implements repository patteren around CosmosDB client API (or your data client, that you are using).

CosmosDB client (and as seems also some others) seems to be designed to be quite aggressive with parallel requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set

ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit

to a higher number like 100 for example and test that out.

Here is the documentation:

[ServicePoint Manager Class [MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

I believe the server that hosts the database(s) needs to increase the limit of dynamic ports it can allow.
The solution is described [here](http://blog.whitesites.com/How-to-Fix-MySQL-Error-10055__635140180116307813_blog.htm#636361346607118637).

Best of luck to you.

Comment: This is a link to a MySQL database issue - nothing to do with Azure, surely?